# Keras-contrib CRF layer "learn-mode" parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, named-entity-recognition, crf

I have just started using CRF layer provided in keras-contrib library for NER (named entity recognition) task. 
The problem I've faced was that while training the model with default parameters, loss is becoming `nan` value in the end of 1st epoch, and never changes.

The thing helped me was changing `learn_mode` parameter of CRF layer to `'marginal'`.

Could anyone please explain the difference between `'join'` and `'marginal'` learn_mode? Why in my case (NER problem) `'join'` mode leads to nan value? Why `'marginal'` works?

```
# input and embedding for words
word_in = Input(shape=(max_len_doc,))
emb_word = Embedding(input_dim=n_words + 2, output_dim=50, 
input_length=max_len_doc, mask_zero=True)(word_in)

# input and embeddings for characters
char_in = Input(shape=(max_len_doc, max_len_word,))
emb_char = TimeDistributed(Embedding(input_dim=n_chars + 2, output_dim=10, 
input_length=max_len_word, mask_zero=True))(char_in)

# character LSTM to get word encodings by characters
char_enc = TimeDistributed(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False,
recurrent_dropout=0.5))(emb_char)

# main LSTM
model_crf = concatenate([emb_word, char_enc])
model_crf = SpatialDropout1D(0.3)(model_crf)
model_crf = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.6))(model_crf)
model_crf = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.3))(model_crf)
model_crf = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="relu"))(model_crf)
crf = CRF(n_tags) # crf = CRF(n_tags, learn_mode='marginal')
out = crf(model_crf)
```

Comment: Hi @Dilshat, did you manage to solve it? Thanks